# Is the past progressive tense the more natural tense to use in this context?

Tags: past-tense, idiomatic-language

If I have just been talking to my son on the phone (I'm not anymore. I have hung up.) and then someone asks me if it was my son whom I was talking to, to which I answer:

> ***"Yes. I was just calling to say goodnight."***

Is the past progressive tense (**'I was just calling'**) the more natural tense to use here?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely works. If you had to choose between wording that sentence "I called to say goodnight" or "I was calling to say goodnight" I would certainly suggest sticking with "I was just calling to say goodnight." This flows and is more cohesive and casual, more natural, than the other two.